# How to prevent error propagation in Apollo Client useQuery in react?

Tags: error-handling, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'd like to catch the error in component level and prevent propagation while using the `useQuery` in @apollo/react-hook.
Here is my example code

```
const invitationDocument = gql`
   query DecodeInvitation($token: String!) {
       DecodeInvitation(token: $token) {
          name
          email
       }
   }
`
const InvitationPage = (props) => {
    const { data, error, loading } = useQuery(invitationDocument, {variables: { token: "XXXX" }});

    if(error)
    {
        return <InvitationErrorPage error={error.message}/>
    }

    return loading? <LoadingPage> : <InvitationAcceptPage />
}
```

It works fine but at the same time, the error is being propagated to its parents level so I get another error notification message which comes from the error handler at the global level.
At the application level, I use the apollo-link-error to manage the Graphql errors.

```
import { onError } from 'apollo-link-error';
const errorLink = onError (({ graphqlErrors, networkError }) => {
    if(graphqlErrors)
       notification.error(graphqlErrors[0].message);
});
const client = ApolloClient({
   cache: new InMemoryCache(),
   link: ApolloLink.from([
            errorLink,
            new HttpLink({ uri: `http://localhost:8080/graphql`})
          ])
})
```

For now, I am finding a solution to stop propagation to top-level so that I can show only `InvitationErrorPage` and stop displaying error notification at the global level.

Comment: WHAT??? ... error link just catches errors from ANY graphql responses, it's a part of response processing ...  no any kind of propagation here .. just remove error link if you don't want it or react only on network errors

Comment: yeah, for general graphl error handling, I'd like to do via error link including displaying notification messages.
But in a specific case, i.e, invitation page in my case, I need to show "ErrorPage" instead of showing general error notification.

Comment: filter by response content [type] ?

Comment: But I can't actually handle the apollo-server and the Invitation query error has no special content type comparing to generals. So filtering by response content [type] doesn't seem a good solution.

Comment: ehhh .... https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/link/apollo-link-error/#ignoring-errors

Comment: I got it. Hopefully, it may resolve my issue

Answer (score 4):

I was also trying to prevent errors from being logged in an Error Link by handling them on a `useQuery` hook and a further delve into the ApolloLink documentation helped clear up what is happening. The key misunderstanding is that the Error Link is not a parent- or application-level handler, it is request middleware. It's helpful to think about how the data is coming back from the server:

[image: Data flow to client through ApolloLink path.]

Thus, when you see an error notification from the Error Link it is not something that "propagated up" from the `useQuery` hook: it occurred in the request path **before** the `useQuery` result was available on the client.

Thus, the `onError` callback for the Error Link will always be called before any error handling code in the `useQuery` hook.

Probably your best bet is to use a combination of the `operation` and `graphQLErrors[x].extensions` to figure out what errors you should pass through the Error Link middleware like so:

```
const errorLink = onError(({operation, response, graphQLErrors}) => {
  if (!graphQLErrors) {
    return;
  }
  if (operation.operationName === "DecodeInvitation") {
    for (const err of graphQLErrors) {
      if (err.extensions?.code === 'UNAUTHENTICATED') {
        // Return without "notifying"
        return;
      }
    }
  }
  // Notify otherwise
  notification.error(graphqlErrors[0].message);
})
```

Comment: You've made a great impact on my understanding of apollo-error-link. This was exactly the solution that I want before. Thanks for your great answer.